# Need plugins for multi select search using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

// Here i tried this plugin but search filter not working

```
<link href="js/multiselect_withsearch/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/multiselect_withsearch/jquery.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Plugins doesn't work by just including scripts!

Comment: I have a large code and i get search filter but it was not coming right .it showing a bullet symbol before the value and the first value was defaultly selected. So, that'y i thought it was a plugin issue.